# Serial communication TIVA microcontroller to windows PC

Tags: c, microcontroller, serial-communication

Ive written C code on both sides TM4C1294 mc and PC. On the mc side I use UARTprintf which can send different data formats %c  %d  %s. I had hoped to find a PC side read function that could directly handle the uint16_t coming from the mc but could not find one. If anyone knows of one this would probably solve my problem which is this: stream the data from the mc (hooked up to a sensor sending data at 40 KHz) to the PC.

1. I tried using CreateFile Windows serial com port tools - ReadFile only accepts bytes of data (of the char X[] sort). So I converted via sprintf(str, "format",data) and sent the string to the PC ok where I converted atoi back to int flawlessly but way too slow for the 40KHz stream (baud rate set at 921600 both sides). The strings contain 4,5 chars to send plus coding/decoding overhead.
2. I converted my int16 data to a hiByte binary and a loByte binary - basically just splitting the int16 in half thus only 2 bytes to send across with a simple bit of bitshift and adding on the pc side to reconstruct the int16. Works great - most of the time ;( Some very nasty things happen when either of the two bytes is a 0x0A or 0x00 - the serial communication inserts a 0x0D into the stream messing up the hiBtye-loByte-hiByte-loByte alternating sequence and I tried to patch it up with some more code but that then introduces lots of IF THEN screening checks slowing down a reasonable data rate near 40KHz to less than 10. Question: is there some efficient way to keep the serial port from interpreting the bytes as ASCII commands like 0x0A is a linefeed?

Comment: Your question is a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text), please put some effort in formatting it.

Comment: It would probably be easier to pinpoint your problem with some example code.

Comment: 'Question: is there some efficient way to keep the serial port from interpreting the bytes as ASCII commands like 0x0A is a linefeed?' no, there is not, because that behaviour does not occur, (at least, not on the Windows side, with MS Windows drivers).

Comment: 'only 2 bytes to send across with a simple bit of bitshift and adding on the pc side to reconstruct the int16' - what happens when ReadFile() returns an odd number of bytes?  It's still not clear how your protocol works?

Comment: I hope you are not issuing a ReadFile() call for just 2 bytes each time:(